# Welch test plus CLT-like sampling procedure for non-normal distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Say that I have two non-normal samples distributions each with n>=1000, for example exponential distributions.

I believe that the typical solution is to use a likelihood ratio test. But I’m curious about the validity of the below procedure:

1. Sample n=25 from each exponential distribution
2. Compute the mean of each sample from 1.
3. Repeat 1,2 40 times.
4. Compute the mean and variance of these approximately normal distributions
5. Perform a Welch test for difference of means.

Is this approach sound?

Infer the sampling distribution mean and standard deviation

Comment: Why not just compute the sample means and their standard errors from the complete sample and perform the Welch test with them?  If $n=25$ gives you an "approximately normal" distribution for the sample means, $n = 1000$ certainly well as well!

Comment: I thought the approximately normal shape didn’t come from a large sample size but from finding the mean of means. Maybe I’m over emphasizing a trivial difference?

Comment: The approximately normal distribution of the sample mean at "large enough" sample sizes comes from the Central Limit Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).  It is entirely sample size dependent, given that the underlying conditions are met.  The "mean of means" will tend towards exactly the same number you calculate from the entire sample; if you work through the math,  you will see its expected value is in fact the mean of the sample.

Comment: I guess I never really understood the CLT. Eg the formulas for normal mean and variance will give the correct mean and variance of non-normal distributions if the sample size is high enough; the repeat sampling and mean of means isn’t required to leverage the implications of the CLT.

Comment: No, you don't actually need to do the repeat sampling.   It's a hypothetical construct used to help explain the result, but it's not actually how the result is derived.  If you have a single sample, its mean will tend towards a Normal distribution as that sample gets larger, roughly speaking, but it's still only a single sample - like one observation from its distribution.

Comment: No need to fuss with CLT or normal approximations. If you have a random sample of size $n$ from an
exponential distribution then $\bar X/\mu \sim
\mathsf{Gamma}(n,n),$ which you can 'pivot' to
get an exact 95% Ci for $\mu$ or to test hypotheses about $\mu.$ For example $\bar X = 23.3$ based on $n = 20$ observations gives 95% CI $( 15.71,\, 38.15)$ for $\mu$ from R code `23.3/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 20, 20)`.